# Installing an Android OTA update without an SD card

Tags: android, updates, recovery, ota, rom

We have a rooted android device and have developed an app and a custom rom for it which was modified from Android 7.1.  We build the roms, no issue.

We install the rom by pushing the OTA update to the sdcard then we give the device a script in /cache/recovery to run once it is rebooted in recovery mode.

The script contains these lines:

```
--update_package=/sdcard/update.zip
reboot
```

This has all worked perfectly fine for years.  The problem is now we want to create a version of the device without an SD card and all attempts to install the OTA update without an SD card have failed.  We are trying to use the internal storage to store the update which of course is not accessible from recovery mode.  Chat GPT has been some help but has not guided us to a solution.

What we've tried / the failure point

-Storing the update in a folder that recovery mode mounts / no permissions to access the update.

-Creating a partition to hold the update / can't mount the partition in recovery mode

-Pushing the update after rebooting in recovery / don't know the command to call to install it

The assumption is that we should be able to do this because, simply, phones do.  But ultimately I would like to know if it's even possible without an SD card.  If so could anyone explain how?

Comment: Are you aware the `/sdcard` uses this name only for historical reasons? On nearly all devices this path points to internal storage, in details to `/storage/emulated/0`

Comment: Yes I am.  The path /sdcard doesn't refer to when in the Android os it refers to that path when in recovery mode, which does in fact point to the SD card.